# QueryDSL AND/ OR Operator Not Working with BooleanExpression

Tags: querydsl

We are Doing a search on an entity , we are using Query DSL .

the table structure is as follows

```
TableA : shop -> has manytoOne relationship to TableB : Discount
```

We need to build a predicate which returns all the shops which does not have discounted
Sale and also that has discounted Sale .

We are Using MySQL Database and JPA as our persistence framework .

Scenario is that we are performing a search and search should get out all the shops with no discounts and shops with discounts approved.

the below are our boolean expressions that we have it at present.

```
BooleanExpression A = shop.id.eq(SomeId);
BooleanExpression B = shop.name.eq(SomeName)
BooleanExpression C = shop.discount.isNotNull;
BooleanExpression D = shop.discount.isNull;
BooleanExpression E = shop.disccount.approved.eq(SomeValue)
```

now we need to build query to get all the shops which don't have a discount , and also all the shops which have a discount and Approved .

we tried with the predicate

```
A
.and(B)
.and(D .or(C.and(D).and(E))
)
```

We expect the query to be

```
where shop.id=#someid and shop.name = 'some name' and (shop.discount is Null Or (shop.discount is not null and shop.approved='#some Value'))
```

but what the query generated is

```
where  shop.id=`#someid` and shop.name = `'some name'` and (shop.discount is Null Or shop.discount is not null and shop.approved='`#some Value`')
```

we are not getting out the proper resultset with this predicate ,

Is there any Way I can rewrite the predicate to make it working as expected ? kindly help me with suggestions.

thanks 
Saravana.

Answer (score 2):

```
A.and(B).and(D .or(C.and(D).and(E)))
```

is equivalent to

```
A and B and (D or C and D and E)
```

See here for MySQL operator precedence https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html

Concerning your example this should work

```
shop.discount.isNull()
.or(shop.discount.isNotNull()
    .and(shop.discount.approved.eq(SomeValue)))
```

Comment: Thanks Timo, Is there anyway we can achieve the requirement using boolean expressions or we have to think in different directions like having 2 predicates for 2 different conditions ? Like One to get shops without discount and one to get shops with discount ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Timo , but still we have the same issue

Comment: `Shop.id.eq(somevalue) .and Shop.sale.isNotNull .and (shop.discount.isNull()
.or(shop.discount.isNotNull()
    .and(shop.discount.approved.eq(SomeValue)))` 
 
 **will be equivalent to**
 
`Shop.id.eq(somevalue) .and 
Shop.sale.isNotNull .and 
(shop.discount.isNull() .or shop.discount.isNotNull() .and shop.discount.approved.eq(SomeValue))`

which is not I want , rather what I need is 

`Shop.id.eq(somevalue)
.and 
Shop.sale.isNotNull 
.and 
(shop.discount.isNull() .or 
(shop.discount.isNotNull() .and shop.discount.approved.eq(SomeValue)))`

Comment: do we need to use any sub queries , Is it possible to achieve this with MYSQL and boolean expression , sorry if I am bothering much , I Just started to Use  query DSL .

Comment: Maybe this could be continued here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/querydsl